# Hausdorff measure of the zero set

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-dimension

Let $f : \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ continuous, for which there exist $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, such that $f(x)f(y)<0$.

Is it true that the Hausdorff dimension of the zero set of $f$ is at least $n-1$?

Comment: In fact the zero set has topological dimension at least $n-1$, and therefore Hausdorff dimension at least $n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true. If the zero set has Hausdorff dimension $<n-1$ then almost every line in the direction of a coordinate axis will not intersect the set. This easily follows from the definition of the Hausdorff dimension. Then you connect your $x$ and $y$ by a piecevise linear curve which does not intersect the zero-set.

Answer (score 0):

IT seems easy to adapt in your case the nice construction of [Sergei Ivanov](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72044/estimating-the-hausdorff-measure-of-a-subset-of-the-sphere?rq=1) of this related question inside the sphere to your case. And the answer would be yes